# Using buttonMarkup on dynamically created elements

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have a jquery draggable and droppable.
The dropped element is cloned from the draggable.
The dropped element is a simple jQuery mobile button.

When I try to modify the dynamically created (dropped) element with the buttonMarkup() method it crates some strange results. The contents of the `< a >` tag is doubled. I am talking about the span elements that are created by jquery mobile.

http://jsfiddle.net/z4gnT/1/

Here is a simple jsfiddle. In this case to make it simple I have used a simple clone instead of draggable/droppable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is because extra styling is appYou'll have to do it this way :

- Create a HTML anchor with `data-role` set to `none`. This will stop the styling on it. Hide this element by default

  ```
  <div class="button-container">     
    <a data-role="button" data-theme="b">Button</a>
    <a class="cloner" data-role="none" data-theme="b">Button</a>
  </div>
  ```
- Now you can use this  button for you cloning.

  ```
  $("#add-icon-button").click(function () {
    //get the button and set it with button data-role and add button markup to it
    var $button = $(".cloner").clone().attr("data-role", "button").buttonMarkup({
      icon: "star"
    }).removeClass("cloner");
    //add the variable inside
    $("#new").html($button);
  });
  ```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/hungerpain/z4gnT/2/